# Options to Common Criteria

Tags: evaluation

There are some critics about the international Common Criteria like [Under-attack].[1](http://gcn.com/Articles/2007/08/10/Under-attack.aspx?Page=1)

What are in your opinion the pros and cons of developing IT products with CC?

Comment: If it's not programming related you'r not likely to get helpful answers here. Sometimes they work but this is more of a discussion style question than a fact finding question. You'll find better luck on a discussion board focused on the topic then you will from the SO community.

Comment: Looks programming related to me! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Criteria
Not a great question, but it is programming related.

Comment: I know I'm biased (see answer below) but I think this is worth an answer, particularly for a developer in a small shop that does both business development and software development. +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a Common Criteria evaluator for the BSI (Germany) and NIAPP (USA) schemes. I've had a small amount of experience, but I think I'm qualified enough to answer this question.

Pros:

1. The first and foremost plus to developing with CC is to be able to do business with the US government. I die inside every time I say this to someone, because I'd really like the top reason to be security. But alas...
2. Secondly, it enormously increases the quality of your design documentation because much of the CC revolves around analyzing documentation, and good docs are a requirement. Find a good lab, and they may do all of that for you.
3. It will make you aware of security questions you never thought about, like how does the customer know the product I shipped to them is really from me and not someone impersonating me?
4. Lastly, sadly, it will improve the technical security of the product. Get a good lab, and you will leave with a very strong secure product and a certification. Get a bad one and you'll just leave with a certification.

Cons:

1. Extremely expensive. Unless you have the deep-enough coffers to absorb a hit of hundreds of thousands of dollars, you're not cut out for CC.  However, if you have the intention of working with the federal government, you may get them to pay your way if they really like your product.
2. Extremely time consuming. Our evaluations last 9-16 months, depending on the complexity of the product and the evaluation assurance level. To give you an idea, a general linux distribution at EAL 4 could take a full year to complete.
3. The certificate only applies to an ***exact*** version number of your product. Make an update and the cert is invalid. (However, its up to the requisitioning officer in the DoD whether to accept the patched product, so not all hope is lost.
4. It's value is almost worthless anywhere outside the federal market.
5. Depending on the scheme you pick, you'll be facing certain kinds of politics, lack of resources, and extra requirements. Best thing to do is find a good lab who will help you through everything.

Note that I'm giving you pro's and con's from the developer's point of view. There are a different set of pro's and con's when talking about technically how the criteria is set up and what it's effectiveness is.

Comment: "The certificate only applies to an exact version number of your product. Make an update and the cert is invalid." ... This really prevents people from doing frequent updates, which means the product cannot keep up with changes in attack vectors, and will make vendors hesitate to keep their products secure. It is almost the most stupid part of CC. The most stupid part is that CC certification holds even when the product clearly is not secure anymore.

Comment: Dear Jeremy, may I have your email address to ask some questions? (Please mention me with "@" mark in your comments).